# Why don't update WEB UI by ajax request in Rails 4?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to update WEB UI of Rails by ajax request triggered from java.
However, it didn't work although I saw 200 OK message.

This is my step I did.

1. Make Ajax request in Java application (using HttpURLConnection object)

   ### - X-Request-With : XMLHttpRequest

   ```
   String url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/java/fromjava";
   String charset = "UTF-8";
   String query = String.format("param1=%s&param2=%s", param1, param2);

   try {
       HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url)
               .openConnection();
       urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
       urlConnection.setUseCaches(true);
       urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
       urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
       urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "ko-KR,ko;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
       urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
       urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
       urlConnection.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
       urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Referer", "http://192.168.43.79:3000/");
       urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36");

       urlConnection.connect();

       OutputStreamWriter writer = null;

       writer = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream(),
               charset);
       writer.write(query);
       writer.flush();

       if (writer != null)
           try {
               writer.close();
           } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {
           }
   ```
2. respond to js in controller

   ### - Set 'rack-CORS' to resolve same origin policy

   ```
   class JavaController < ApplicationController

   skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

     def fromjava
       respond_to do|format|
         format.js
       end
     end

   end
   ```
3. change WEB UI

   ```
   [fromjava.js.erb]
   $('#container').empty().append('This is [ajax] text');

   [java.html.erb]
   <div id="container">
       This is default text
   </div>
   ```
4. Log message in log/development.log

   ```
   Started POST "/java/fromjava" for 127.0.0.1 at [current date]
   Processing by JavaController#fromjava as */*
     Rendered java/fromjava.js.erb (0.0ms)
   Complete 200 OK in 43ms (View: 39.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
   ```

I saw the 200 OK message in log. However, Didn't update WEB UI. What is the problem?

Also, Are there other way to track the progress of the request & response ??

Comment: First you need to make sure that you are passing the the `.js` in your request url in order to get the response based on `fromjava.js.erb`. Second could you please show us the full content of your `fromjava.js.erb`

Comment: I checked that fromjava.js.erb received request in log file. Do I have to set request header to pass the request to .js file ??

Comment: I updated this question. You can see full content of fromjava.js.erb. That's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First** 
you need to make sure that you are passing the the `.js` in your request url in order to get the response based on `fromjava.js.erb`. your url in the java code should be

```
String url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/java/fromjava.js";
```

**Second** as I can see in the `fromjava.js.erb` you just passing a jQuery code, OK but you need to make sure that the jQuery code is being executed once the response is received on the client side, you just send the response which is code but it hasn't been executed on the client's machine.

Comment: How can I check whether jquery statement of fromjava.js.erb is executed ??

Comment: I tried "String url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/java/fromjava.js" but, It doesn't work althought I saw 200 OK.

Comment: I updated my answer with the correct url that should be passed. by the way your `java.html.erb` has no effect here as it is not part of your response

Comment: Your main issue is to make sure that the jQuery code is executed after the response is being received.

Comment: In the question, I saw the 200 OK and rendered java/fromjava.js.erb. Can I make sure the execution of jquery statement by this message ??

Comment: where does the response go, normally if you initialize the ajax request from client's side the response goes to that client. but here the request initialized from Java app, the question where the response go?

Comment: OK your have specified the client url and port number in your request. just noticed it. OK the issue when the browser receives that response it doesn't execute it. I think you need to specify the expected type of the data when I response is received.

Comment: One thing I used to do with Javascript which I expect a js code I pass the reponse to `js eval function` so you need to pass your response to `javascript eval function` or whatever is equivalent in jQuery

Comment: Maybe respond to java because I didn't set the destination of response in Java. Can I set the destination of response in HTTP Reuqest Header??? I tried same url with your answer, However didn't work. Also, What is the mean of rendered  "java/fromjava.js.erb" message. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know the way to pass to javascript eval function. Can you show me some example ??

Comment: I know that the 200 OK message means that my intent(jquery statements) was executed in WEB, However I didn't see the result of my intent. Am I misunderstand the mean of 200 OK message ? If the log message is correct, is there another view that have same url ? and is it possible ?

Comment: 200 means that HTTP resquest was executed successfully on server. the status number indicates that the request was execute successfully and here is the the response if something went wrong on the server during request execution you will receive a response as well but with different status code based on the error occurred on the server. So the 200 has nothing to do with executing the jQuery code, it just means that your request was executed and response received with jQuery code but it doesn't mean that jQuery code has been executed.

Comment: Please read this ***[post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests/2793153#2793153)*** it gives you a good idea on how to create a good http request and handle its response with Java

Comment: Thank you. I will check your link. Your answer was very helpful.